# Misunderstanding of C# class vs struct

Tags: c#, lambda, copy

I was trying to implement an automatic differentiation C# lib based on a Python example but I have an issue with the lambda / local function (kind of vague, not sure why it doesn't work).
I even implemented the thing in another language: Kotlin succesfully ... So I probably have a misunderstanding of some programming part either something related to narrow / deep copy or lambda / local function.

```cs
public static Value operator +(Value a, Value b)
{
    var ret = new Value(a.Data + b.Data, new[]{a, b});

    void B()
    {
        a.Gradient += ret.Gradient;
        b.Gradient += ret.Gradient;
    }

    ret._backward = B;
    return ret;
}
```

I give this little piece of code but it's better to look at the whole: [full code with tests in 3 languages](https://gist.github.com/louis030195/80ce2fdd2c475bef09267399b0be0b79)

The Gradient doesn't change strangely, I don't know how to give a better explanation of the problem.

Comment: Please only tag questions with the actual language you're asking about, not other languages that happen to be mentioned as examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `Value` from being `struct` i.e. [value type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types) to `class` i.e. [reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types):

```
public class Value
{
    ...
}
```

As docs state:

> A variable of a value type contains an instance of the type. This differs from a variable of a reference type, which contains a reference to an instance of the type. By default, on assignment, passing an argument to a method, and returning a method result, variable values are copied. In the case of value-type variables, the corresponding type instances are copied

so changes to fields of local `a` and `b` inside `operator +` function will not affect the values outside.

Comment: Omg thank you ! Been stuck on this for a while, got it ... using a class properly update the gradient by reference

Comment: @LouisBeaumont was glad to help!